# Building .dmg package requires Apple Developer ID

Tags: macos, javafx, build, dmg, apple-id

I am trying to build a .dmg package for my JavaFX application using Eclipse and e(fx)clipse, but it gives me the following error:

```
Did not find a key matching 'Developer ID Application: '

BUILD FAILED
/Users/xxx/git/xxx/xxx/build/build.xml:203: Error: Bundler "DMG Installer" (dmg) failed to produce a bundle.
```

There are plenty of threads out there on how to use a valid Apple Developer ID certificate in this situation. But according to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingApplicationsOutside/DistributingApplicationsOutside.html) Apple page the only reason to sign an app with an Developer ID certificate is the following:

> If your app isn’t signed with a Developer ID certificate issued by
>   Apple, it won’t launch on a Mac that has Gatekeeper enabled.

But having to disable Gatekeeper to be able to launch the app is fine by me. Especially since I am currently mostly interested in packaging the application as a .dmg for testing purposes.

So is it possible to build a .dmg package for my JavaFX application without using a Developer ID?

Comment: In the past, I had packaged my projects into DMG packages without the need for a  `Developer ID`. I am not sure if things have changed in recent times, but it was definitely possible when I used to do it. I will try it again when I have time and provide you with more inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that all you needed to do was to disable Gatekeeper on the building machine to be able to build the .dmg package. No idea why they implemented it like that. Regardless, that is the answer to my question. Thank you for the answers that demonstrated that it was possible to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

This is still possible (as of 1.8.0_76) and I do that all the time.
My deploy settings are:

```
    <fx:deploy
        verbose="true"
        embedJNLP="false"
        extension="false"
        includeDT="false"
        offlineAllowed="true"
        outdir="${basedir}/deploy"
        outfile="???"
        nativeBundles="dmg"
        updatemode="background" >

        <fx:info title="???" vendor="???"/>
        <fx:application refId="fxApplication"/>
        <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>
    </fx:deploy>
```

You will have to substitute the ??? with your own names.

Answer (score 1):

I had just the same, in my case the solution was to umount an already mounted dmg File:

df -h
and then
umount /Volumes/...

Comment: Worked for me (unmounted previously mounted dmg volumes)